# Uri.parse('https://www.a2rstore.in/api/school/v1/noticeApi.php?id=${widget.s_id}'); got error on widget.s_id

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

```
class Notice extends StatefulWidget {
  final String s_id;

  const Notice({Key key, this.s_id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NoticeState createState() => _NoticeState();
}

class _NoticeState extends State<Notice> {
  TextEditingController _titleController = new TextEditingController();

  var api =
      Uri.parse('https://www.a2rstore.in/api/school/v1/noticeApi.php?id=${widget.s_id}');
```

Comment: Please provide the context where this code is used and the full error message.

Comment: actually I want to do add a variable in api link.

Comment: @julemand101 please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515391/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value-or-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtyp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the "widget" without the context.
The proper way to do it is by first defining your variable:

```
class _NoticeState extends State<Notice> {
  TextEditingController _titleController = new TextEditingController();

  var api;
  ...
}
```

And then assigning to it the value either in the build or initState method:

```
@override
initState(){
   api = Uri.parse('https://www.a2rstore.in/api/school/v1/noticeApi.php?id=${widget.s_id}');
}
```

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515391/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value-or-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtyp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537861/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value , please check this one i don't understand anything what is problem in this code