# error: Null check operator used on a null value OR List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

fetch Two different pages api with same uniq id
I want the user_uniq_id of the API of the button and the user_uniq_id of the API of the team_list to match and show the data of its user after the match.

this code is for first File
This code is of the button that is coming from the api

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/left_team.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonState createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  var api = Uri.parse('http://192.***.***.***/flutter/teamApi.php');
  var response;
  var teamApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() async {
    response = await http.get(api);
    print(response.body);
    teamApi = jsonDecode(response.body);

    setState(() {});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var color = 0xff453658;
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff392850),
        title: Row(
          children: [

            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),

            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Income",
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),

          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),

            onPressed: () => print("open cart"),
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Color(color))),
            child: Row(

              children: [
                Text(
                  "Total Income:",
                  style: TextStyle(

                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  width: 10.0,
                ),
                Text(

                  "Rs.2000",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ],
            ),

          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),

          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              child: GridView.count(
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,

                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 18,
                mainAxisSpacing: 18,

                children: List.generate(
                  teamApi.length,
                  (index) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {

                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>

                                LeftTeam(teamData: teamApi[index])),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(

                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xff00ffff),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Column(

                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(
                            child: Text(teamApi[index]["teamType"],

                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),

                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

This is API data of button

```
[{"teamType":"direct team","team_name":"platinum","team_number":"234","team_uniq_id":"1","team_last_update":"10-may-2021"},{"teamType":"left team","team_name":"gold","team_number":"356","team_uniq_id":"2","team_last_update":"10-may-2021"},{"teamType":"right team","team_name":"silver","team_number":"876","team_uniq_id":"3","team_last_update":"10-may-2021"}]
```

this is code for second file.
this is model part.

```
class MyData {
  List<Results> user = [];

  MyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // previous = json['previous'];
    // next = json['next'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      user = <Results>[];
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        user.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Results {
  String user_name = "";
  String user_mother_name = "";
  String user_address = "";
  String user_mobile = "";
  String user_sponsor_id = "";
  String sponsor_id = "";
  String email = "";
  String city = "";
  String state = "";
  String dob = "";

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    user_name = json['user_name'];
    user_mother_name = json['user_mother_name'];
    user_address = json['user_address'];
    user_mobile = json['user_mobile'];
    user_sponsor_id = json['user_sponsor_id'];
    email = json['email'];
    city = json['city'];
    state = json['state'];
    dob = json['dob'];
  }
}
```

this provider of api link.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:practice/LeftTeamFile/model/myData.dart';

class MyHomePageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyData? data;
  Future getData(context) async {
    
    var url = Uri.parse(
  var url = Uri.parse('http://192.***.***.***/flutter/team_list.php');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    print("res${response.body}");

    var mJson = json.decode(response.body);
    this.data = MyData.fromJson(mJson);
    this.notifyListeners();
```

this is teamList part .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/LeftTeamFile/provider/myHomePageProvider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TeamList extends StatefulWidget {
  final teamData;

  const TeamList({Key? key, this.teamData}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TeamListState createState() => _TeamListState();
}

class _TeamListState extends State<TeamList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            height: 100.0,
            color: Color(0xffedbf6b),
            child: Row(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(

                        Icons.list_alt,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.teamData['team_uniq_id'],

                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          SizedBox(

            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider<MyHomePageProvider>(

                create: (context) => MyHomePageProvider(),
                child: Consumer<MyHomePageProvider>(
                  builder: (context, provider, child) {
                   if (provider.data!.team_uniq_id ==
                        widget.teamData['team_uniq_id']) {
                      print("prov $provider.data");

                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        // Data table widget in not scrollable so we have to wrap it in a scroll view when we have a large data set..
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: DataTable(
                    
                          columns: [
                             DataColumn(
                             label: Text('Name'),
                             tooltip: 'represents if user is verified.'),
                            DataColumn(

                                label: Text('Mother_name'),
                                tooltip: 'represents first S no of the user'),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('address'),
                                tooltip: 'represents Sponsor ID of the user'),

                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('mobile'),
                                tooltip: 'represents User ID of the user'),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('User_s_id'),

                                tooltip: 'represents Name of the user'),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('sponsor_id'),
                                tooltip: 'represents Mobile of the user'),
                            DataColumn(

                                label: Text('email'),
                                tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('city'),
                                tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),

                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('state'),
                                tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                            DataColumn(
                                label: Text('dob'),
                                tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                          
                          ],

                          rows: provider.data!.user
                              .map((data) =>
                                  // we return a DataRow every time
                                  DataRow(
                                      // List<DataCell> cells is required in every row

                                      cells: [
                                       red when unverified
                                        DataCell(Text(data.user_name)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.user_mother_name)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.user_address)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.user_mobile)),

                                        DataCell(Text(data.user_sponsor_id)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.sponsor_id)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.email)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.city)),

                                        DataCell(Text(data.state)),
                                        DataCell(Text(data.dob)),
                                      ]))
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );

                  },  provider.getData(context);
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is teamlist api

```
[
  {
    "teamType": "direct Team",
    "team_uniq_id": "1",
    "user": [
      {
        "user_name": "deepak",
        "user_mother_name": "Accomodation",
        "user_address": "varanasi",
        "user_mobile": "5678989",
        "user_sponsor_id": "123456",
        "sponsor_id": "3456",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com",
        "city": "varanasi",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "12-5-1996"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "deepak",
        "user_mother_name": "Accomodation",
        "user_address": "varanasi",
        "user_mobile": "5678989",
        "user_sponsor_id": "123456",
        "sponsor_id": "3456",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com",
        "city": "varanasi",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "12-5-1996"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "deepak",
        "user_mother_name": "Accomodation",
        "user_address": "varanasi",
        "user_mobile": "5678989",
        "user_sponsor_id": "123456",
        "sponsor_id": "3456",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com",
        "city": "varanasi",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "12-5-1996"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "teamType": "left Team",
    "team_uniq_id": "2",
    "user": [
      {
        "user_name": "Ashu",
        "user_mother_name": "manju",
        "user_address": "Mirzapur",
        "user_mobile": "222222",
        "user_sponsor_id": "123456",
        "sponsor_id": "3456",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com",
        "city": "varanasi",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "12-5-1996"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "Ashutodh",
        "user_mother_name": "manju1",
        "user_address": "Mirzapur1",
        "user_mobile": "2222221",
        "user_sponsor_id": "1234561",
        "sponsor_id": "34561",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com1",
        "city": "varanasi1",
        "state": "India1",
        "dob": "12-5-19961"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "teamType": "Right Team",
    "team_uniq_id": "3",
    "user": [
      {
        "user_name": "tosh",
        "user_mother_name": "snju",
        "user_address": "Allahabad",
        "user_mobile": "44444444",
        "user_sponsor_id": "333456",
        "sponsor_id": "6666666",
        "email": "jkl@gmai.com",
        "city": "lucknow",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "15-3-1956"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "teamType": "Total Team",
    "team_uniq_id": "4",
    "user": [
      {
        "user_name": "tosh",
        "user_mother_name": "snju",
        "user_address": "Allahabad",
        "user_mobile": "44444444",
        "user_sponsor_id": "333456",
        "sponsor_id": "6666666",
        "email": "jkl@gmai.com",
        "city": "lucknow",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "15-3-1956"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "deepak",
        "user_mother_name": "Accomodation",
        "user_address": "varanasi",
        "user_mobile": "5678989",
        "user_sponsor_id": "123456",
        "sponsor_id": "3456",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com",
        "city": "varanasi",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "12-5-1996"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "deepak",
        "user_mother_name": "Accomodation",
        "user_address": "varanasi",
        "user_mobile": "5678989",
        "user_sponsor_id": "123456",
        "sponsor_id": "3456",
        "email": "abc@gmai.com",
        "city": "varanasi",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "12-5-1996"
      },
      {
        "user_name": "tosh",
        "user_mother_name": "snju",
        "user_address": "Allahabad",
        "user_mobile": "44444444",
        "user_sponsor_id": "333456",
        "sponsor_id": "6666666",
        "email": "jkl@gmai.com",
        "city": "lucknow",
        "state": "India",
        "dob": "15-3-1956"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I feel some error is coming.
[image]

Comment: Your team-list API returns a JSON List but you are handling the JSON using `this.data = MyData.fromJson(mJson);` where `MyData.fromJson` expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`. You should handle the data as you are doing with the results.

Comment: @julemand101 but after using Map<String, dynamic> then i got error on mJson.

Comment: Yes, using `Map<String, dynamic>` will give you an error since you are having `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. You need to go though each element in the list.

Comment: @julemand101 if you don't mind, Can you write code please? I have seen and yet the error is coming.

Comment: I hope some other can help you. It is going to take me to much time to import your Flutter project since I don't have any Flutter environment installed on my machine (I am only using the Dart SDK).

Comment: @julemand101 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537861/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value ,check this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make sure you convert the object you are getting from the server to list, to be able to pass in the list into the widget