# error: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

In this, when the uniq_id of the button and the uniq_id of the data table match, only then the data of the user of that uniq_id will show.
But this error is coming before the data shows.

[image]

Did show the data for one time but after this error came, for both the page

This is my p_team.dart
This is the part of the button that is coming from the Api.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/listPost/p_team_list.dart';
import 'package:practice/post/post.dart';
import 'package:practice/post/services.dart';

class PTeam extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PTeamState createState() => _PTeamState();
}

class _PTeamState extends State<PTeam> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Post>? posts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Services().getPosts().then((list) {
      (() {
        posts = list;
        print(posts);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [

          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.greenAccent)),

            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Total Income:",
                  style: TextStyle(

                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10.0,

                ),
                Text(
                  "Rs.2000",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(

            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              child: GridView.count(
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),

                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 18,
                mainAxisSpacing: 18,
                children: List.generate(
                  posts!.length,
                  (index) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {

                      print(posts![index].teamUniqId);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => PTeamList(
                                  teamUniqId: posts![index].teamUniqId,
                                  teamType: posts![index].teamType,

                                )),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xff00ffaa),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),

                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(
                            child: Text(posts![index].teamType,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,

                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

This is my button api's data for p_team.dart.

```
[{"teamType":"direct team","team_name":"platinum","team_number":"234","team_uniq_id":"1","team_last_update":"10-may-2021"},{"teamType":"left team","team_name":"gold","team_number":"356","team_uniq_id":"2","team_last_update":"10-may-2021"},{"teamType":"right team","team_name":"silver","team_number":"876","team_uniq_id":"3","team_last_update":"10-may-2021"}]
```

this is my p_team_list.dart.

In this, when the uniq_id of the button and the uniq_id of the data table match, only then the data of the user of that uniq_id will show.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/listPost/post_list.dart';
import 'package:practice/listPost/services.dart';

class PTeamList extends StatefulWidget {
  final teamUniqId;
  final teamType;

  const PTeamList({Key? key, this.teamUniqId, this.teamType}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PTeamListState createState() => _PTeamListState();
}

class _PTeamListState extends State<PTeamList> {
  List<Post>? posts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Services().getPosts().then((list) {
      setState(() {
        posts = list;
        print("za$posts");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // if(widget.teamUniqId==posts.)
    return Scaffold(
      body:
          // Text(widget.teamType),
          Flexible(

        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: List.generate(posts!.length, (index) {
              if (posts!.length == null) {
                print(posts![index].user);
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

              } 
else if (widget.teamUniqId == posts![index].teamUniqId) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  // Data table widget in not scrollable so we have to wrap it in a scroll view when we have a large data set..

                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: DataTable(
                      columns: [
                        // DataColumn(
                        // label: Text('Verified'),
                        // tooltip: 'represents if user is verified.'),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('S No'),

                            tooltip: 'represents first S no of the user'),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('Sponsor ID'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Sponsor ID of the user'),
                        DataColumn(

                            label: Text('User ID'),
                            tooltip: 'represents User ID of the user'),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('Name'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Name of the user'),
                        DataColumn(


                            label: Text('Mobile'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Mobile of the user'),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('Date'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                        DataColumn(

                            label: Text('a'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('b'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                        DataColumn(

                            label: Text('c'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('d'),
                            tooltip: 'represents Date of the user'),
                      ],
                      rows: posts![index]
                          .user
                          .map((data) =>
                            

                              DataRow(
                                  cells: [
                                  
                                    // I want to display a green color icon when user is verified and red when unverified
                                    DataCell(Text(data.userName)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.userMotherName)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.userAddress)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.userSponsorId)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.sponsorId)),

                                    DataCell(Text(data.email)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.city)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.state)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.userMobile)),
                                    DataCell(Text(data.dob)),
                                  ]))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Text("");
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

This is my data table api's data for p_team.dart.

```
[{"teamType":"direct Team","team_uniq_id":"1","user":[{"user_name":"deepak","user_mother_name":"Accomodation","user_address":"varanasi","user_mobile":"5678989","user_sponsor_id":"123456","sponsor_id":"3456","email":"abc@gmai.com","city":"varanasi","state":"India","dob":"12-5-1996"},{"user_name":"deepak","user_mother_name":"Accomodation","user_address":"varanasi","user_mobile":"5678989","user_sponsor_id":"123456","sponsor_id":"3456","email":"abc@gmai.com","city":"varanasi","state":"India","dob":"12-5-1996"},{"user_name":"deepak","user_mother_name":"Accomodation","user_address":"varanasi","user_mobile":"5678989","user_sponsor_id":"123456","sponsor_id":"3456","email":"abc@gmai.com","city":"varanasi","state":"India","dob":"12-5-1996"}]},{"teamType":"left Team","team_uniq_id":"2","user":[{"user_name":"Ashu","user_mother_name":"manju","user_address":"Mirzapur","user_mobile":"222222","user_sponsor_id":"123456","sponsor_id":"3456","email":"abc@gmai.com","city":"varanasi","state":"India","dob":"12-5-1996"},{"user_name":"Ashutodh","user_mother_name":"manju1","user_address":"Mirzapur1","user_mobile":"2222221","user_sponsor_id":"1234561","sponsor_id":"34561","email":"abc@gmai.com1","city":"varanasi1","state":"India1","dob":"12-5-19961"}]},{"teamType":"Right Team","team_uniq_id":"3","user":[{"user_name":"tosh","user_mother_name":"snju","user_address":"Allahabad","user_mobile":"44444444","user_sponsor_id":"333456","sponsor_id":"6666666","email":"jkl@gmai.com","city":"lucknow","state":"India","dob":"15-3-1956"}]},{"teamType":"Total Team","team_uniq_id":"4","user":[{"user_name":"tosh","user_mother_name":"snju","user_address":"Allahabad","user_mobile":"44444444","user_sponsor_id":"333456","sponsor_id":"6666666","email":"jkl@gmai.com","city":"lucknow","state":"India","dob":"15-3-1956"},{"user_name":"deepak","user_mother_name":"Accomodation","user_address":"varanasi","user_mobile":"5678989","user_sponsor_id":"123456","sponsor_id":"3456","email":"abc@gmai.com","city":"varanasi","state":"India","dob":"12-5-1996"},{"user_name":"deepak","user_mother_name":"Accomodation","user_address":"varanasi","user_mobile":"5678989","user_sponsor_id":"123456","sponsor_id":"3456","email":"abc@gmai.com","city":"varanasi","state":"India","dob":"12-5-1996"},{"user_name":"tosh","user_mother_name":"snju","user_address":"Allahabad","user_mobile":"44444444","user_sponsor_id":"333456","sponsor_id":"6666666","email":"jkl@gmai.com","city":"lucknow","state":"India","dob":"15-3-1956"}]}]
```

Comment: why you need two `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: @JohnJoe It may have happened by mistake but it does not matter on the error, the error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @RCvaram https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537861/error-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value , please check this one i don't understand anything what is problem in this code

Comment: Please try to put your question in an understandable way. No one has time to waste on decoding your problem is in first place :) Here we help solving questions, not decoding them

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is that you're using a bang `!` operator on a null value. This indicates that the Object can't be null, and throws an error if so.

You can either add a null check at the start or if the value can be null, it's best to use a nullable `?` operator instead.

The error can be easily demonstrated with

```dart
int? foo; // nullable var
  
debugPrint('${foo!}'); // with the ! operator, Flutter expects the value to never be null
```